# Zoom on product image doesnt work - RWD theme

Tags: magento-1.9, product-images, zoom

The zoom on product images only seems to work, when the images are square. Whenever they are not, no zoom pops up.

I am using a slightly modified version of the RWD theme. The problem also occurs when switching to the original RWD theme though.

Any ideas?

Comment: What have you tried so far, in terms of debugging. Please update your question with more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the images were too small for the elevateZoom plugin.

One could force them to be big enough by doing something like:

`$this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image')->resize(800,600)`

Answer (score 0):

There is not enough information in your post to answer your question. To identify and debug the issue, the URL of your page is required.

It is quite common for image zooming not to show on non-standard Magento themes. The fix is usually to modify the template, ensuring that the zoom JavaScript and CSS files are being referenced; that the template is fetching the correct size for large and small images and that there are no conflicts with other scripts in the template.

In all cases, ensure that product images you uploaded are sufficiently large to be zoomed. At least 500px width and preferably more than 800px width. The larger the image, the higher quality the zoom. Some small images may not zoom at all.

Also consider installing a Magento image zoom extension that already supports the RWD theme such as [Magic Zoom Plus](https://www.magictoolbox.com/magiczoomplus/modules/magento/). Zoom extensions typically support many themes by default.

Comment: Thanks man, and sorry for not explaining my question properly. Turns out those specific images where the elevateZoom plugin didnt work, were simply too small.